# How do I map duplicate values ​in a CSV file to a structure in Java

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file that contains over a million items with the following structure:

```
1,Foo,null
1,Bar,null
2,Foo,00.01
2,Bar,null
3,Foo,null
3,Bar,null
4,Foo,null
5,Foo,null
5,Bar,00.01
5,Baz,00.05
...
```

My problem is that I have to wrap it in a structure that will allow me (in the next steps) to operate on the values ​​that are at positions 2 and 3 of csv (1,2,3).
The first item is an id that can repeat itself.

Finally, I need something like this:

```
1 | Foo | null
  | Bar | null
  
2 | Foo | 00.01
  | Bar | null
  
  ...
```

So far I was able to parse the CSV and as a result I have the following list:

```
List<MyCategory> myCategory ...


class MyCategory {
    private String id;
    private String field;
    private String level;
    
    
    //getters, setters
    
  }
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to do afterwards. You can either transform it to a map, or simply order it. However, looking at the input, it is already ordered

Comment: `Map<Integer, List<MyCategory>>` would fit the bill probably

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve it this way:

```
class FData {
    private String field;
    private String level;
    
}

FData fData;
List<FData> fDataList;
Map<String,List<FData>> fMap = new HashMap<>();

for (MyCategory m : myCategory) {
    if (!fMap.containsKey(m.getId())){
       fData = new FData(m.getField(), m.getLevel());
       fDataList = new ArrayList<>();
       fDataList.add(fData);
       fMap.put(m.getId(), fDataList);
     } else {
          fData = new FData(m.getField(), m.getLevel());
          fMap.get(m.getId()).add(fData);
     }
}
```